# Amazon S3 file upload fails sometimes using the Java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am experiencing a really weird behaviour while uploading files to AmazonS3.

Most of the time (97% of the total uploads) this code works flawlessly. The other 3% the `putObject` method executes correctly but afterwards I can't recover the file. It is not present in the bucket.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public String uploadAppFileToS3(File file, Long appId, String fileName) throws IOException {

FileInputStream stream;

BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(s3AccessKey, s3SecretKey);
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
    .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_3) //eu-west-3 EU(Paris)
    .build();

String contentType = Files.probeContentType(file.toPath());
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentType(contentType);
stream = new FileInputStream(file);
metadata.setContentLength(file.length());

String fileS3Key = appId + "/" + fileName;
s3.putObject(s3BucketName, fileS3Key, stream, metadata);

//Clear resources
stream.close();

return fileS3Key;
}
```

This code gets called from a Spring Boot endpoint:

```
/**
 * This method will handle the file upload to Amazon S3
 */
@PostMapping("/application/upload/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public AppFileDTO uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable Long id,
    Model model) throws IOException {

  //Get the app from the database
  Application app = applicationService.findById(id);
  model.addAttribute("app", app);

  //Store the file temporarily
  File temporalFile = new File(temporalStoragePath + file.getName());
  file.transferTo(temporalFile);

  String fileS3Key = appFileService
      .uploadAppFileToS3(temporalFile, app.getId(), file.getOriginalFilename());

  //Delete the file
  temporalFile.delete();

  //Now create the domain object for the file and associate it to it's parent
  AppFile appFile = new AppFile();
  appFile.setApp(app);
  appFile.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
  appFile.setS3Key(fileS3Key);
  appFileService.create(appFile);

  //Send a mail to the employees indicating that a new file has been uploaded.
  emailService.sendNewFileUploadNotification(appFile);

  //Create a DTO and return it to the front end
  AppFileDTO appFileDTO = new AppFileDTO();
  appFileDTO.setFileId(appFile.getId());
  appFileDTO.setCreationTimestamp(app.getCreationDate());
  appFileDTO.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());

  return appFileDTO;
}
```

As you can see, after the call to the service that uploads the file to S3, there is a call to a notification service that sends an email. That email is sent perfectly, meaning that the call to the `putObject` method did not throw any Exceptions.

If we take a look at the `putObject` documentation we find this:

> Amazon S3 never stores partial objects; if during this call an
>   exception wasn't thrown, the entire object was stored.

And this:

> The client automatically computes a checksum of the file. This
>   checksum is verified against another checksum that is calculated once
>   the data reaches Amazon S3, ensuring the data has not corrupted in
>   transit over the network.

So until now i've got:

- The putObject method does not throw any Exceptions
- I know that for sure because the mail is being sent, it would never reach that line of code in the case that S3 threw an Exception.
- The S3 docs state that if something goes wrong with the upload it will throw an error.
- The file does not end up in the bucket.

I've already made sure that the filename is specified in the multipart request.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am encountering the same thing.

Comment: Nope, sorry. I think it only happened 2 times more since I posted the question. But it's still a mystery for me.

Answer (score 0):

I see that [AWS recommends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/best-practices.html) using streams that support mark and reset, which FileInputStream does not. Perhaps the SDK is trying to handle a network problem with a mark/reset, in which case the stream would throw "java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported".